# How to sort files by word count in linux?

Tags: linux, command-line, command

I have to sort files in current directory based on word count by using command `wc` and pipe `|` necessarily.
What command do I have to use?

I thought I had to use a command `sort | wc -w`, but I failed.

Comment: You mean sorting files based on number of words they contain?

Comment: yes the problem was "• Sort files in current directory based on word count
– Hint : wc and pipe"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this can help.

```
ls -1 | xargs wc -w | sort
```

The `ls -1` will list all files of the current directory, and then pass it to `xargs` to use the output of the previous command as input of the command `wc -w`. Finally we pipe the result to `sort` command to order them by number of words each file contain.
You can learn more about `xargs` [here](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/xargs.1.html).

The output:

```bash
[amirreza@localhost test]$ ls -1
four_words
three_words
two_words
[amirreza@localhost test]$ ls -1 | xargs wc -w
 4 four_words
 3 three_words
 2 two_words
 9 total
[amirreza@localhost test]$ ls -1 | xargs wc -w | sort
 2 two_words
 3 three_words
 4 four_words
 9 total
```

### Edit

I just figured out that my answer was not correct. Because `sort` command by default works character by character, so the result of sorting `2`, `10`, `3` will be:

```
10, 2, 3
```

Because it only checks the first character of `10` and it's `1` so it's less than `2` and `3`.
To fix it we should use numerical sort, by using `n` flag. Here's how it works:

```
[amirreza@localhost test]$ ls -1 | xargs wc -w | sort
10 ten_words
19 total
 2 two_words
 3 three_words
 4 four_words
[amirreza@localhost test]$ ls -1 | xargs wc -w | sort -n
 2 two_words
 3 three_words
 4 four_words
10 ten_words
19 total
```

And just to make output more cleaner we can remove the `total` line and just show the file names.

```
[amirreza@localhost test]$ ls -1 | xargs wc -w | sort -n | awk  '{print $2}' | head -n -1
zero_word
two_words
three_words
four_words
ten_words
```

Comment: I love you,........... you are my Einstein....... I got it thank you so much T0T

Comment: @hhhamster I hope it helps :)